# How to know if user has verified his/her email address

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase Auth 9.6.1 Release(Android).

I am able to send the verification link to user email address.
But I don't understand how to know if the user has verified his/her email address?
Is there any way to know that user has verified the email address successfully so that I can change the status of his/her account Pending to Active.

Comment: Hello , how did you manage to send a verification mail ? Im trying everything but cant get an email sent.

Comment: @user6650650 he did it with `user.sendEmailVerification()`, read [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: @user6650650 Yes I am able to send email also verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access `UserInfo` instance you can call [`isEmailVerified()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo.html#isEmailVerified()) on it. See [changelog](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.6). It was added in release **9.6.1**.

Comment: Thank you dear, sorry I missed it.